# Why will $\epsilon - N$ proof not work if we pick a random $L$ that is not the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

By definition, we know that

> $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb{N} \text{ such that } n > N \implies |a_n - L| < \epsilon$

Normally, we will need to find an $N$ such that $N > f(\epsilon)$ for some function $f$ and make $N$ as the ceiling of $f(\epsilon)$, which will finish the proof.

However, what would happen if we select an $L$ such that $L$ is not the limit of the sequence?

Comment: *Where f() is derived from |−L|

Comment: What happens is the definition of a limit does not apply to a value that is not the limit. If the sequence $a_n$ has a limit and you pick another value for $L$, then for some small enough value of $\epsilon>0$, you can only find finitely many values of $a_n$ such that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: You can try seeing what happens if you tried to show that $1/n$ has limit $0.2$ instead of $0$, for example (i.e. it might be instructive to try some specific example and see what happens).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have tried to show that 1/  has limit 0.2 and I have found some  that will not work for the definition. (For example, if  = 0.3 then |−|<  will be false.)

Comment: @Adolphus Actually, with $\epsilon=0.3$, $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ is true for all $n>2$. Not a good counterexample, but you can find another value of $\epsilon$. Hint: the limit of $a_n$ is $0$, so pick a value of $\epsilon$ such that $L-\epsilon>0$. Probably easier with a drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if we choose  an $\;L\;$ that is not the limit, then there will be some $\;\epsilon>0\;$ such that for any $\;N>f(\epsilon)>0\;$  there will be some index $\;n>N\;$ with $\;|a_n-L|\ge \epsilon\;$ ...I just wrote down the logical negation of the definition you wrote.

In fact it can be even simpler, beginning with the definition: we say $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=L\;$ if for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exists a natural number $\;N_\epsilon\;$ (depending on epsilon) s.t. whenever $\;n>N_\epsilon\;$ , then $\;|a_n-L|<\epsilon\;$ . No need to introduce some mysterious function $\;f(\epsilon)\;$, though it doesn't really matter.

Now, negating the simpler definition is: $\;L\;$ is *not* the limit of a sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ if for some $\;\epsilon>0\;$ it happens that for any $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ we can always find some $\;n>N\;$ such that $\;|a_n-L|\ge \epsilon\;$

Answer (score 3):

In that case, for some $\epsilon>0$, you are not able to find such $N$ that satisfy the limit condition.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of putting it is to say that if $a_n$ converges the limit is unique.

Assume $L_1\not = L_2$ are $2$ limits.

For $\epsilon >0 $ exists a $n_1(\epsilon)$ s.t.

for $n\ge n_1:$ $ |a_n-L_1|< \epsilon$.

Likewise: There exists a $n_2(\epsilon)$ s.t.

for $n\ge n_2$: $|a_n-L_2| <\epsilon.$

Let $N=\max(n_1,n_2)$.

For $n\ge N(\epsilon)$:

$|L_1-L_2| =|L_1-a_n+a_n -L_2| \le$

$|a_n-L_1|+|a_n-L_2| <2\epsilon.$

A contradiction for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.